# Github Action add "needs" with separate workflow file

Tags: github, github-actions

I have got two workflows:

- workflow1.yaml
- workflow2.yaml

I need in workflow2.yaml add something like:

```
jobs:
  build_kotlin:
    runs-on: [server1, server2, server3]
    needs: [workflow1]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

Currently "needs" doesn't work properly. How can reference separate workflow yaml file?

Answer (score 6):

`needs` is only used to establish relationships between jobs -- not entire workflows.

If you want to run "workflow2.yaml" after "workflow1.yaml" has been completed, then add a trigger like so:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [workflow1]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  build_kotlin
    # ...
```

Read more on [Events That Trigger Workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run)

Alternatively, you could make workflow1 a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) and then make sure it is executed before workflow2 like so:

```yaml
jobs:
  workflow1:
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/workflow1.yaml@main

  build_kotlin:
    runs-on: [server1, server2, server3]
    needs: [workflow1]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
```